# Failed to pass JSON Object

Tags: c#, javascript, json, web-services, telerik

I'm trying to call the server side method and passing value with Json format using $.ajax() ,but I got this error:

```
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:   \u0027obj\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

When i hardcoded the values & try to send,then thats correct..but unable to pass Json Object.

Client Side Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function DailyReportFn() {

    debugger;
    var RadTabStrip1 = $find("<%= RadTabStrip1.ClientID %>");
    var tab = RadTabStrip1.findTabByText("Qualified Families");
    var RadPageView1 = tab.get_pageView()
    var elment = RadPageView1.get_element();


    var DailyReport = {

        NewReg: $find("<%= NewReg.ClientID %>").get_textBoxValue(),
        Removed: $find('<%= Removed.ClientID %>').get_textBoxValue(),
        Homevt: $find('<%= Homev.ClientID %>').get_textBoxValue()
    }



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/DModules/Hc/WebMethods.aspx/DemoReport")%>',
        data: JSON.stringify(DailyReport),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert(x.responseText);
        },

    });
}
```

Server Side Code

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod] 
public static int DemoReport(Drep report)
{
    int result = -1;

    int NewReg = report.NewReg;
    int Removed = report.Removed;
    int Homev = report.Homevt;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What javascript library are you using that has `$find`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data: JSON.stringify({report:DailyReport}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you do the post,try to check the value of JSON.stringify(DailyReport) first.

```
var DailyReport = {
    NewReg: $find("<%= NewReg.ClientID %>").get_textBoxValue(),
    Removed: $find('<%= Removed.ClientID %>').get_textBoxValue(),
    Homevt: $find('<%= Homev.ClientID %>').get_textBoxValue()
}
console.info(JSON.stringify(DailyReport));//OR: alert(JSON.stringify(DailyReport));

$.ajax({...
```